# How to write lists in different directions in pandas in python

Tags: pandas

I have three lists as follows.

```
list_names_1 = ["Salad", "Bread"]
list_names_2 = ["Oil", "Fat", "Salt"]
list_values = [[0.2, 0.1, 0.8], [0.2, 0.9, 0.8]]
```

Now I want to write the aforementioned three lists to a csv file as follows.

```
NAMES, Oil, Fat, Salt
Salad,  0.2, 0.1,  0.8
Bread,  0.2, 0.9,  0.8
```

That is, I want the `list names_1` in vertical direction, `list_names_2` in horizontal direction and `list_values` as the values of the two lists.

Is it possible to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_values, columns=list_names_2, index=list_names_1)
df.index.name = 'NAMES'
print (df)
NAMES  Oil  Fat  Salt
Salad  0.2  0.1   0.8
Bread  0.2  0.9   0.8

df.to_csv('file')

NAMES,Oil,Fat,Salt
Salad,0.2,0.1,0.8
Bread,0.2,0.9,0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.DataFrame(data=.., columns=..., index=...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to construct the dataframe.

And, use [`index_label`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) in [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to get the name as `NAMES` set in output.

```
In [2167]: print (pd.DataFrame(data=list_values, columns=list_names_2, index=list_names_1)
                    .to_csv(index_label='NAMES'))
NAMES,Oil,Fat,Salt
Salad,0.2,0.1,0.8
Bread,0.2,0.9,0.8

(pd.DataFrame(data=list_values, columns=list_names_2, index=list_names_1)
   .to_csv('name.csv' index_label='NAMES'))
```